# Need utility / guidance to register a linux device (hostname, ip address) on DNS server using microsoft dynamic dns on intranet. Is it possible?

Tags: embedded-linux, dyndns

I have a linux device which gets an IP address over dhcp and then it needs to register itself on DNS server using microsoft DDNS so that it can be accessed on the intranet using it's hostname. Is there any client utility which can be used or do so without changing anything on the dns?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by the DHCP client. Many embedded linux use dhclient whis does not send the host name to the DHCP server, but some others (like [pump](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=collab-maint/pump.git)) do.

If we want to be precise, dhclient has a small support for DNS updates. In the manpage of dhclient.conf you can read

> The  client  now has some very limited support for doing DNS updates
>   when a lease is acquired.   This is prototypical, and probably doesn't
>   do what you want.   It also only works if you happen to have control
>   over your DNS server, which isn't very likely.
>
> Note that everything in this section is true whether you are using
>   DHCPv4 or DHCPv6. The exact same syntax is used for both.
>
> To make it work, you have to declare a key and zone as in the DHCP
>   server (see dhcpd.conf(5) for details).   You also need to configure
>   the fqdn option on the client, as follows:
>
> ```
>  send fqdn.fqdn "grosse.fugue.com.";
>  send fqdn.encoded on;
>  send fqdn.server-update off;
>  also request fqdn, dhcp6.fqdn;
> ```
>
> The  fqdn.fqdn  option  MUST  be  a  fully-qualified  domain  name.
>   You  MUST  define a zone statement for the zone to be updated. The
>   fqdn.encoded option may need to be set to on or off, depending on the
>   DHCP server you are using.

so I think that evaluating other DHCP clients is the best solution